# regular expression to match 4 or more identical characters

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need regular expressions to match the below case.

4 or more consecutive identical characters/numbers; e.g. 1111, aaaa, bbbb, 2222, etc.

I tried this pattern matching

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z\\d])\\1\\1", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

But i found that it matches only 3 or more identical characters.

1. Please let me know what change i need to make it match 4 or more identical characters.
2. Also i need to check for special character "\" . Please tell me how i need to add in the pattern matching statement ...do i need to give as "\\" ?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use {3,} as well...

```
"([a-z\\d])\\1{3,}"
```

instead of  adding \\1 multiple times (haven't tried this in java).

Comment: I think it will be `([a-z\\d])\\1{3,}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another backreference:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z\\d])\\1\\1\\1", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Basically, the parenthesis indicate a matched group. From there the three backslashed ones, refer to this matched group, meaning that all four groups must be the same.

Comment: Can it be made shorter in Java like other languages i.e. `(.)\1{3,}`?